# How to store values from select query when using odbc_exec in php

Tags: php, odbc

I currently have the following php code :

```
$select = "
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM [MEMBERS]
    WHERE [MEMBER_ID] = 'carl'";

    $result = odbc_exec($connection, $select);


    if($result){
        if(check if count matches){
        do something
    }
    }else{
    error if select query fails
    }
```

I have been searching around for a way to retrieve the value returned by the sql and store it within a variable so I can check whether it matches. Any help would be great.

I have tried to use the following but couldn't get it working:
`$value=odbc_result_all($result, "Cellpadding='3' background-color='d3d3d3'");`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use odbc_fetch_array function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php ?

Comment: Please don't just give a link, provide a code example if you think something is able to answer the OP's question